# xpath query not grabbing any information - python

Tags: jquery, python, html, css, xpath

I am trying to grab some information off [this page](http://www.mountainproject.com/v/my-other-woman-is-a-hand-crack/107465606)

but there are three pieces of data I have been unable to grab.  The first is the grade, which is the '5.6' next to the YDS near the top.  The second is FFA: P.Adamson, M.Peck July 2008, listed next to FA:.  The third is Trad, 30', listed next to type.

The xpath queries I have are

```
grade = tree.xpath('//[@id="rspCol800"]/div[1]/div[1]/span/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()')

length = tree.xpath('//*[@id="rspCol800"]/div[1]/div[1]/span/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()')

first_ascent = tree.xpath('.//*[@id="rspCol800"]/div[1]/div[1]/span/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/text()/text()')
```

I have tried to grab grade from a few different places on the page, as it is listed in a couple places but no such luck yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What happens with the queries you've tried?  Do they find incorrect results?  Do they find nothing at all?  Do they produce an error?

Comment: they find nothing at all.  I'm outputting to a txt file and other information grabbed from the page will come in the form [text here], but these three fields produce only []

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what framework you are using but this seems to work:

```
from lxml import html
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.mountainproject.com/v/my-other-woman-is-a-hand-crack/107465606')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = response.read()
tree = html.fromstring(data)
grade = tree.xpath('//div[@id="rspCol800"]/div[1]/div[1]/span/table/tr[2]/td[2]/span/text()')[1]
length = tree.xpath('//*[@id="rspCol800"]/div[1]/div[1]/span/table/tr[1]/td[2]/text()')[0]
first_ascent = tree.xpath('.//*[@id="rspCol800"]/div[1]/div[1]/span/table/tr[3]/td[2]/text()')[0]

print grade, length, first_ascent
```

Comment: yup this worked!  I only had one problem with the grade query, which produced not only the 5.6 grade but also all other hidden grades (there are multiple grades buried within that field), as well as a bunch of characters like /xa0, etc.  I just parsed through the string to grab the first (5.numberhere) that it encountered after /xa0.

Also for framework I'm using lxml and requests so my first few lines ended up a bit different, but I don't think it changed anything

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hm, that '[1]' at the end of the 'grade' line seemed to grab a single 5.6 for me . Perhaps, requests lib transcodes the page in a different way. You can also do data = data.replace("&nbsp;", "") to get rid of the unwanted spaces (that's what there \xa are). Or do grade=grade.strip().